# Performance comparison: Google us-east-1 vs AWS us-east1 when trying to reach AWS us-east1

Tags: performance, amazon-web-services, google-cloud-platform

I am planning running a web app that will need to make 3rd party HTTPS posts to `AWS US-EAST1`. However, I am far more familiar with Google Cloud Platform.

Has anyone quantified the performance disadvantages from running in `Google US-EAST-4` vs `AWS-EAST1` when trying to reach `AWS-EAST1`?

Comment: Why Google us-east1 (South Carolina) and not Google us-east4 (Northern Virginia)?  AWS us-east-1 is in Northern Virginia.

Comment: Thanks, I'll edit the question accordingly.